# Templated constructor, parenthesis expected

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class template:

```
template <class T>
class NormalEstimator
{
    public:
        NormalEstimator(pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr cloud) : _cloud(cloud) {}

        void computeNormals();
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr getNormals();
    private:
        typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr _cloud;
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr _normals;

        int _kNeighbours;
};
```

The member functions are declared in the header file as well. When compiling, this gives me the error:

```
.../normal_estimator.h:12: error: expected ')' before 'cloud'
```

Am I forgetting something? Do I need to specify 'typename' on the constructor as well in some way or form?

Comment: See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/420683)

Comment: `pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr` is a dependant name because T is a template parameter. You have to write `typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need `typename` in the constructor parameter as well because `T` is a dependent type:

```
NormalEstimator(typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr cloud)
//              ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to read up on templates and dependent types.

Answer (score 2):

It's a dependent name. The type `::Ptr` is dependent on T. So you have to use "typename" to tell the compiler that the value of `::Ptr` is a type.

```
 NormalEstimator(typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr cloud)
```

This is because as long as T is defined the type of ::Ptr might be anything (a static member / type / static function).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
NormalEstimator(typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr cloud) : _cloud(cloud) {}
```